# Why is $\lim\limits_{x\to0}x\sin(1/x)=0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

How $\lim\limits_{x\to0} x\sin(1/x)=0$
When $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\sin(1/x)$ doesn't exist?
I got this result by calculating it manualy and by wolphram alpha too.
I took $-1\le\sin(1/x)\le1$ and by multiplying it by $x$ i got $0$. But still $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\sin(1/x)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Well... $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x}$ doesn't exist either, but nevertheless $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} x \frac{1}{x}$ does?

Comment: To understand the _limit_ at $0$ you do not need to know anything about the _value_ at $0$.

Comment: @prets yes exactly, that is my question how can second exist if the first one doesn't?

Comment: I think you are thinking that $\lim[f(x)g(x)]=(\lim f(x))(\lim g(x))$, but this is not always true. Here $|x\sin(\frac1x)|\le|x|$ so the limit is $0$ by the sandwich theorem.

Comment: Because whatever goes wrong in the former is counteracted by (in these cases) multiplying by $x$. In my example, $1/x$ blows up near $x = 0$, but it blows up *as quickly* as $x$ goes to $0$, so they "balance". In your example, $\sin(1/x)$ is extremely wild near $x = 0$, but it is *bounded* there, and so as $x \to 0$, $x \sin(1/x)$ dampens the wild behaviour.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\sin(1/x)$ doesn't exist in the sense that it's value is indeterminate, but even though it's indeterminate, sine function only takes finite values, and when multiplied with $x$, overall value approaches $0$ as $x$ approaches $0$.

Comment: Use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1959736).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3774391/if-fx-x-sin-frac-pix-is-continuous-everywhere-then-find-f0/3774513#3774513

Comment: $|x\sin{\frac{1}{x}}|\le |x||\sin{\frac{1}{x}}|\le |x|$ so given $\epsilon\gt 0$, $|x|\lt\epsilon\implies ...$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is the source of your confusion. When you look at $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\ x\ \text{sin}(1/x)$, which does exist, you try to apply the limit product rule, which would give
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\ x\ \text{sin}(1/x) = \left(\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\ x\right)\left( \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\ \text{sin}(1/x)\right)$$

The above statement is false because $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\ \text{sin}(1/x)$ does not exist.
Now, where did we go wrong to arrive at a false statement? We applied the product rule when it could not be applied. Theorem conditions are VERY important. The product rule says that IF the separate limits $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}\ f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}\ g(x)$ exist, THEN you can apply the product rule $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}\ f(x)g(x)=\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow c}\ f(x)\right)(\lim_{x\rightarrow c}\ g(x))$. The condition is not met in your example, so it is perfectly ok for the product rule result not to hold.